# Extracting strong text and following p's

Tags: python

I have written a code to extract a div (see below), but now i would like to show all the "strong" in one column  and the following text in a different column (for multiple files in a directory). In dropbox i uploaded an example: (https://www.dropbox.com/s/kbnal2pefih2ru4/test.html?dl=0).

My code till this far is:

```
import textwrap
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

directory ='C:/Research syntheses - Meta analysis/SeekingAlpha/Tests/'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
        fname = os.path.join(directory,filename)
        with open(fname, 'r') as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),'html.parser')
            participants = soup.find('div',class_='content_part hid', id='article_qanda')
        print(filename, participants)
```

So my output would need to be: in column 1 all the strongs and in column 2 the following p (sometime more than one). I hope someone can help me!

Comment: What's the issue, exactly?

Comment: Hi @AMC i have some parsed htmls, but i want to use the strongs as identifier for the p text coming after this strong tag. The answer below works, only i need a solution to pass html files which do not have this div-qanda in its body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through all the partecipants and save a temporary array with the columns of each rows. Then you can display them as you wish. This is an example:

```
import textwrap
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

fname = "test.html"
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),'html.parser')
    participants = soup.find('div',class_='content_part hid', id='article_qanda')

n=-1
rows = []
for p in participants:
    name = p.find("strong")
    if name is not None and str(name) != "-1":
        n = n + 1
        rows.append([name.text])
    elif name is None:
        rows[n].append(p.text)

# now print all the rows
for r in rows:
    if len(r) > 1: 
        # here you can display them as you wish.
        #   r[0] contains the "strong" tag
        #   r[1] contains the next "p" tag
        print("%s => %s" % (r[0], r[1]))
    else:
        # here you have only the "strong" tag
        print(r[0])
```

Edit:

I removed `class_='content_part hid',` from the `soup.find`, removed one loop and added the multiprocess part, you can find info about multiprocess [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html):

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import multiprocessing as mp

def process(filename):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
       fname = os.path.join(directory,filename)
       with open(fname,errors='ignore') as f:
           soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),'html.parser')
           participants = soup.find('div', id='article_qanda')
       if not participants:
          return

       for p in participants:
           name = p.find("strong")
           if name is not None and str(name) != "-1":
               print()
               print(name.text + " => ", end='')
           elif name is None:
               print(p.text, end=' ')

directory ='.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = mp.Pool()
    p.map(process, os.listdir(directory))
```

Comment: awesome!! But there are also some html which do not have qanda and i want these to be ignored. How could this be fixed?

Comment: Hi this code is running quite slow, i am using this code on app 75.000 htmls and it isn't yet half way and it took already 10  hours. Do you have an idea to improve the processing time? Maybe writing to a txt file may help?

Comment: i edited the answer, now on my pc with 6500 files like the one you linked in the question it took 2 minutes more or less. By the way if the answer helped you, can you accept it?

Comment: thanks, strange the code is now already running for 6 hours and still not finished.

Comment: i think i found my problem. Could you modify the code that the output is saved (txt)?

Comment: You can just redirect to file both in linux and in windos like this: `python test.py > result.txt`. Just curious how long does it take to process all the files?

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: hi one additional question, the output txt gives me some strange codings like:"JÂ³rgen Wagner - MainFirst Bank", could i resolve this by adding a coding like UTF7 in the original code? Or should this be done in the windows code "python test.py > result.txt"?

Comment: I'm not really an expert about encodings, anyway this is what I whould try: use `, encoding=""` options in the `open()` when you read the file. The other options is to convert the encoding of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Using the code of @rxw, i have edit his answer further in my final solution:

```
import textwrap
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import textwrap
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

directory ='C:/Research syntheses - Meta analysis/Transcripts'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
        fname = os.path.join(directory,filename)
        with open(fname,errors='ignore') as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),'html.parser')
            participants = soup.find('div',class_='content_part hid', id='article_qanda')
            if not participants: continue
            n=-1
            rows = []
            for p in participants:
                name = p.find("strong")
                if name is not None and str(name) != "-1":
                    n = n + 1
                    rows.append([name.text])
                elif name is None:
                    rows[n].append(p.text)

                # now print all the rows
                for r in rows:
                    if len(r) > 1: 
                        # here you can display them as you wish.
                        #   r[0] contains the "strong" tag
                        #   r[1] contains the next "p" tag
                        print("%s => %s" % (r[0], r[1]))
                    else:
                        # here you have only the "strong" tag
                        print(r[0])
```